# Do I need to send an email to say thank you?

Tags: email

I'm not very familiar with English world, and I want to ask a question about Email etiquette.

Sometimes I sent an email to someone for help, and got a very helpful reply which completely solved my problem. When I was going to reply him, I found I have no more questions, so what I replied contains only two words 'Thank you'.

Do I really need to send this 'Thank you' letter? I think it's polite to show my gratitude, but it may also disturb him because this letter contains no real content.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: VTC; This is not actually on-topic. That being said, showing gratitude and courtesy will never hurt you. You might want to make it a little longer or more specific, and say "Thank you for taking the time to help me!" or "Thank you for helping me to solve my problem!" and add "I really appreciate it."

Comment: I agree with @Lauren that this is off-topic. @Lynn That would also be off-topic since it'd be a pretty subjective question to answer.

Comment: It is always appropriate to say thank you, even if it is all you say.

Comment: Would you appreciate a thank-you email if you'd helped someone? Yes, of course you ould. So send one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting and very insightful question. Absolutely, a "thank you" email is appropriate when someone has helped you solve a problem, and it's very unlikely anyone would be disturbed by it.

In many cases, the person who helped you is doing this as part of his or her job, and needs to know if the problem is solved, or if it requires further action. In any case, people like to feel their efforts are successful and appreciated.

The only instance I can think of where a thank-you note is not strictly necessary is where the email explicitly says that your issue is considered resolved if you do not reply within a specified time. This is something you'll see with companies that use automated email tracking systems.

And by the way, your English is not bad at all. You express yourself at least as well as most native English speakers.